# How to intercept event in method

Tags: c#, events

I have an event

```
public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> OnMyEvent;
```

And I want subscribe to this event in my method, intercept one triggering this event and unsubscribe on this event.

That code is not working...

```
    private string InterceptMessage()
    {
        EventHandler<MyEventArgs> handler = null;
        string message_intercepted = null;

        handler = (sender, e) =>
        {
            message_intercepted = e.Message;
            OnMyEvent -= handler;
        };

        OnMyEvent += handler;

        return message_intercepted;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for my english

Comment: Your function makes no reference to the `OnMyEvent` event.

Comment: this smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: This goes against the spirit of events. You should be writing a custom structure to handle this.